# Cyclic type reference in f#

Tags: .net, generics, f#

I am writing simple excel formula to linq expressions builder in F#. I'm parsing formulas to AST and building expressions using recursive expression builder. I've stucked on passing environment (map of (string, expression) pairs) to generated expression in that call:

```ml
Expression.Lambda<System.Func<double>>(eval pexpr).Compile()
```

Where pexpr is parsed AST and eval is expression builder function.

The problem is with defining type that should look like this:

```ml
type ExprFunc = Func<ExprFunc map, double>
Expression.Lambda<ExprFunc>(eval pexpr).Compile()
```

If pexpr contains reference to other expression in form of Var("name"), i want to inject expression that searches function with "name" in environment map and call it, passing the same environment map in that call.

Unfortunately, compiler says no:

This type definition involves an immediate cyclic reference through an abbreviation

Is there any way to define such function type in .net?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to write a type declaration that references itself, you cannot use F# type alias. The problem is that an F# type alias is erased at compile-time, so a recursive reference would lead to an infinite type:

```
Func<Func<Func<Func<... map, double> map, double> map, double> map, double>
```

In F#, the easiest alternative is probably to define a simple discriminated union:

```
type ExprFunc = EF of Func<ExprFunc map, double>
```

Then you can use the pattern `EF f` to get the underlying delegate in an F# function. Doing this directly won't work with `Expression.Lambda` though, so you'll probably need something like:

```
type ExprFunc = Func<ExprFunc map, double> 
and WrappedExprFunc = EF of ExprFunc
```

When calling `Expression.Lambda`, you'll need to use the `Func<..>` delegate as an argument, but you'll need to modify the code in `eval` to properly handle wrapped arguments (which will be of type `WrappedExprFunc`):

```
Expression.Lambda<ExprFunc>(eval pexpr).Compile()
```

As an aside, if you're generating C# expression trees, it might be easier to define `WrappedExprFunc` as a class, because that is easier to process. That depends on the rest of your code.